# How can I start this image loop on click of button?

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
       <p align="center">

<button onclick="slideit()">Run the loop</button>

   <!-- Start Weather Image Loop -->

<img src="firstcar2.gif" name="slide" width="900" height="500" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var imagevis1=new Image()
imagevis1.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image1.jpg"
var imagevis2=new Image()
imagevis2.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image2.jpg"
var imagevis3=new Image()
imagevis3.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image3.jpg"
var imagevis4=new Image()
imagevis4.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image4.jpg"
var imagevis5=new Image()
imagevis5.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image5.jpg"
var imagevis6=new Image()
imagevis6.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image6.jpg"
var imagevis7=new Image()
imagevis7.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image7.jpg"
var imagevis8=new Image()
imagevis8.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image8.jpg"
var imagevis9=new Image()
imagevis9.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image9.jpg"
var imagevis10=new Image()
imagevis10.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image10.jpg"
var imagevis11=new Image()
imagevis11.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image11.jpg"
var imagevis12=new Image()
imagevis12.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image12.jpg"
var imagevis13=new Image()
imagevis13.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image13.jpg"
var imagevis14=new Image()
imagevis14.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image14.jpg"
var imagevis15=new Image()
imagevis15.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image15.jpg"
var imagevis16=new Image()
imagevis16.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image16.jpg"
var imagevis17=new Image()
imagevis17.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image17.jpg"
var imagevis18=new Image()
imagevis18.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image18.jpg"
var imagevis19=new Image()
imagevis19.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image19.jpg"
var imagevis20=new Image()
imagevis20.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image20.jpg"
var imagevis21=new Image()
imagevis21.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image21.jpg"
var imagevis22=new Image()
imagevis22.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image22.jpg"
var imagevis23=new Image()
imagevis23.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image23.jpg"
var imagevis24=new Image()
imagevis24.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image24.jpg"
var imagevis25=new Image()
imagevis25.src="http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image24.jpg"

//-->
</script>
<script>
<!--

//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("imagevis"+step+".src")
if (step<25)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds

if (step<25)
{
setTimeout("slideit()",100)
}
else
{
setTimeout("slideit()",1500)
}
}
slideit()

//-->
</script>
<!-- End Weather Image Loop -->

   </p>
```

I am trying to load this script with the click of a button, but when I place the lower script in a function, and load it with the button, it does not start the loop. For whatever reason, it sometimes says that `slideit()` is not defined, or that the first image (`imagevis1`) is not defined.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: BURN IT! `eval("imagevis"+step+".src")` Why in the world would someone use eval to do string concatenation? yikes, that is some poor coding.

Comment: Why don't you show what you tried with loading it with a button?

Comment: @epascarello this among other things ...

Comment: I can't really burn it. You have any clues on how to start it onClick of button?

Comment: You call `slideit()` with the click event. And how come #25 is the same as #24?

Comment: You guys want my attempts? Okay, hold on... i'll edit my question.

Comment: Are you trying to create an animation with all the images?

Comment: Yeah. When I call slideit(), it starts before the button is clicked anyway (yet, the image loop is sketchy).

Comment: #25 is the same as #24 because, for whatever reason, the loop flies back to the first image on the #25th, so I made the last TWO images the same (temporary fix, works alright).

Comment: If you guys have a better code to do this, please give it to me in an answer. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: **Why did you guys downvote my question?? I'm just trying to get the code to work, I didn't write it!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why yours is not working is the fact you never removed the slide() call which starts it off. You would need to remove that and the code would work with the button click.

```
    setTimeout("slideit()",1500)
    }
}
slideit()  <-- REMOVE THIS LINE

//-->
</script>
<!-- End Weather Image Loop -->
```

---

But the code has other issues. I wrote this rather quick, but this is a little better than what you have. The preload could be done differently if they are not loading in time.

HTML :

```
<img src="" id="slideshow" />
<button id="btn">Animate</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    var srcStart = "http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image",
        srcEnd = ".jpg",
        start = 1,
        end = 24,
        current = start,
        shortDelay = 100,
        longDelay = 1500,
        elem = document.getElementById("slideshow"),
        btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
        isPreload = true;

    function next() {
        var delay = shortDelay;        
        elem.src = srcStart + current + srcEnd;
        current++;

        if(current!==end) {
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = srcStart + (current+1) + srcEnd;
        }
        if(current>end) {
            current = start;
            delay = longDelay;
        }
        window.setTimeout(next,delay);
    }

    btn.onclick = next;
})();
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7qUY/

Comment: I see. I took `slideit()` away and called it from the button. This loads the loop when the button is clicked, but the code is secretly loading all of the images beforehand. My goal is to load all of the images on the button click as well. Do you know how to make this happen? I appreciate it.

Comment: Put them into a function. Call the function onclick.

Comment: I put them in a function just now and called them on click: `<button onclick="slideit();loadingimages();">Run the loop</button>` but now, the button doesn't do anything?!

Comment: Once I can load images and display them onClick of the button, I will confirm your answer. You have been the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the function slideit() defined inside your wrapper function.

```
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1;
function slideit(){
    //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
    if (!document.images) {
        return;
    }
    document.images.slide.src=eval("imagevis"+step+".src");
    if (step<25) {
        step++;
    } else {
        step=1;
    }
    //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
    if (step<25) {
        setTimeout("slideit()",100);
    } else {
        setTimeout("slideit()",1500);
    }
}
var button = document.getElementById("YourButtonID");
button.addEventListener("click", slideit);
```

You need the image tag named `slide` because your javascript uses that attribute to target the image tag to update `document.images.slide.src=eval("imagevis"+step+".src");`.

Also make sure that your `setTimeout` methods have the times you intend. Your comment says you want to call `slideit()` every 2.5 seconds but your calls are using 100 and 1500 milliseconds which is .1 and 1.5 seconds respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to write an animation or something.

html

```
<img src='http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image1.jpg' id="weatherImg" width="400" />
<input type="button" id="animate" onclick="animate()" value="tiempo" />
```

JavaScript

```
currImg=0;
images = [
"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image1.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image2.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image3.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image4.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image5.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image6.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image7.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image8.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image9.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image10.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image11.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image12.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image13.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image14.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image15.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image16.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image17.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image18.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image19.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image20.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image21.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image22.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image23.jpg"
,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image24.jpg"
//,"http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/data/us_comp/big/image25.jpg"
];
aniClock = 0;
animate = function(){
clearTimeout(aniClock);
    if (typeof images[currImg] == "undefined"){
        //alert('ho');
        //return false;
        currImg = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("weatherImg").src = images[currImg];
    currImg++;
    aniClock = setTimeout(function(){animate();},300);
}
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/bVye6/